# "\envs unexpected at this time" Anaconda Command Prompt

Tags: python, windows, installation, 32bit-64bit, anaconda

I need to have both a 32-bit and 64-bit install of Anaconda. I've installed both of these to my user directory as "Anaconda3" and "Anaconda3 (32-bit)". I mostly use the 64-bit version so during the installation I unchecked the options: "Add Anaconda to my PATH environment variable", and "Register Anaconda as my default Python 3.5" for the 32-bit install.

Now, when I go to the start menu folder to find "Anaconda Command Prompt" under the 32-bit version it is not there. If I go to where the start menu shortcuts are located I can find it, but when running the shortcut for Anaconda Command Prompt it doesn't run and I get the message, "\envs was unexpected at this time".

If it helps, the target for the Anaconda Command Prompt shortcuts on my system for each version are:

32-bit : `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda3 (32-bit)\Scripts\activate.bat" "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda3 (32-bit)"`

64-bit : `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda3`

So my questions are:

1. What is causing this error?
2. What is the proper way to go about having both of these versions installed?